# Ambiguous reference to member 'insert(_:completionHandler:)' xcode 8 beta 2

Tags: xcode, xcode8, imessage, xcode8-beta2

Hello with the new beta 2 i got a new problem that i couldn't solve.

```
var message = MSMessage() 
var template = MSMessageTemplateLayout()

viewDidLoad() {    
     if let filePath2 =
     Bundle.main().pathForResource("synth", ofType: "wav") {
         let fileUrl = NSURL(string: filePath2)
         let URL2 = fileUrl as! URL
         template.mediaFileURL = URL2
     }

 message.layout = template

 guard let conversation = activeConversation else {

 fatalError("Expected a conversation") }  conversation.insert(message,
     localizedChangeDescription: nil) { error in
     if let error = error {
         print(error)
     }
 }
}
```

anyone else have the same problem? there's something wrong with conversation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no MSConversation method `insert(_:localizedChangeDescription:)`. Look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msconversation) and see.

Did you mean `insert(_:completionHandler:)`? If so, just delete the second parameter.

Comment: when i write this it is not even throwing any error and not inserting as a message(tableview: didselect {   MSConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error in inserting -- \(error)")
            }
        }) })  .  Can you please help